# Is it possible to build a react native menu over my gonative app which uses obj c / java?

Tags: android, objective-c, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios

I created a Gonative.io app for my website inwiththem.com and couldn't figure out how to replace my top bar navigation with a native version in Objective C, I also could not figure out how to add a footer menu for android at the bottom but found working source code to use but do not know how to implement it. Both versions and source files have been uploaded to my Github:
https://github.com/Getinwiththem/Them-For-iOS
https://github.com/Getinwiththem/Them-For-Android

Would anyone be interested in helping me finish this project? I’m not familiar at all with Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ready made library to do the job, then `react-native-navigation` is what you need. You will only need to follow the installation instructions and don’t have to work extensively with Objective C

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure how to add it into the current source code that i have in github. What would I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Their documentation is already details enough and honestly I couldn't find an easier way to help. In case you need the documentation link. It's here: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/